# Get Selected value from Radio Button . (a star rating) in Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I'm use this Star Rating:
[Star Rating](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/star-rating-widget/)

and put it into my form. 
There is a way to get the selected value (star) in C# code?

```
<div class="starRating">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
          <label for="rating1"><span>1</span></label>
        </div>
        <input id="rating2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
        <label for="rating2"><span>2</span></label>
      </div>
      <input id="rating3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
      <label for="rating3"><span>3</span></label>
    </div>
    <input id="rating4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
    <label for="rating4"><span>4</span></label>
  </div>
  <input id="rating5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
  <label for="rating5"><span>5</span></label>
</div>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: add ``runat="server"`` or use ``<asp:RadioButton>`` means server side radio button

Comment: hi thanks.
I try to use asp radio button but the css in this tutorial not fit.
and which element here should has attribute of runat="server" ?

Comment: all radio inputs like ``<input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1" runat="server">`` or you can store clicked radio button value in a hidden field by jquery and access it in code behind